# React.js Toggling Display

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to toggle a content on my page with a button in React.js If I press the button, I want the content to disappear. If I press it again, I want the content to reappear again. I tried everything that I can think of, but nothing seems to work. I initially tried a ternary statement to see if I can toggle, but it just breaks my application. Can someone tell me how I can improve this part of the project? Here is what I have:

```
//App.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isToggle: false
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ !isToggle ? isToggle: true : isToggle: false });
  }

  render() {

    const style = {
      display: none
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-xs-center">List of items:</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Toggle</button>
        <div className="container" style={!isToggle ? style.display = none : style.display = block}>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Basically, I want to toggle the Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be its shape if I were to make up the component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggle: false};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({isToggle: !this.state.isToggle});
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-xs-center">List of items:</h1>
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          Toggle
        </button>
        <div
          style={{display: this.state.isToggle ? 'block': 'none'}}
          className="container"
        >
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help! I guess my first mistake was the `handleClick` method. I should have just change the state to the opposite of what it was instead of doing a ternary condition. The second mistake was I forgot to wrap the content of my style in `{}` and no need to make a `const style`.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much about it. Note also that I bind `this` to `handleClick` in the constructor instead of the render function. The render function will run over and over each time `state` changes, so does the `bind` method as a result. It becomes redundant and can be optimized away.

Comment: I am learning react and it was so hard to find the answer to this problem the line style={{display: this.state.isToggle ? 'block': 'none'}} was enough for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional rendering instead of CSS:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isVisible: false
    };
    this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
  }

  onToggle(e) {
    this.setState({isVisible: !this.state.isVisible});
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-xs-center">List of items:</h1>
        <button onClick={this.onToggle} className="btn btn-primary">Toggle</button>

        {this.state.isVisible &&
          <div className="container">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my way

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isShow: false
        };
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        this.setState({
            isShow: !this.state.isShow
        });
    }

    getComponent() {
        if (this.state.isShow) {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return '';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-xs-center">List of items:</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Toggle</button>
                {this.getComponent()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line..

```
        <div className="container" style={!isToggle ? style.display = none : style.display = block}>
```

to...

```
<div className="container" style={!isToggle ? {display:'none'} : {display: 'block'}} >
```

inline 'style' should return a JSON object {{key: 'value, key2': 'value2'}}.

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for thanks a lot Raja

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you try assign an style.display to style attribute in HTML, it's wrong, change that part and it should all work, Try this below:

```
//App.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isToggle: false
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ !isToggle ? isToggle: true : isToggle: false });
  }

  render() {

    const style = {
      display: none
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-xs-center">List of items:</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Toggle</button>
        <div className="container" style={!isToggle ? {display:'none'} : {display: 'block'}}>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

For more info about how style works, look at the link below:

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow function to do this. Much simpler and cleaner in my opinion.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggle: false};
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-xs-center">List of items:</h1>
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={ () => this.setState({ isToggle: !this.state.isToggle }) }
        >
          Toggle
        </button>
        <div
          style={{display: this.state.isToggle ? 'block' : 'none'}}
          className="container"
        >
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```